# check out form that would match zipcode to an email

Tags: javascript, html, cgi

I need to create a check out form that would automatically select a zip code from the billing address on the form and match the zip code with an assigned email. Each email will have multiple zip codes assigned to them. The form that I currently have is in cgi and I am not sure if it can implement this since it doesn't actually run off a data base.

I am looking for any opinion on how to accomplish this with out creating a database.
I am familiar with java script, php and html (cgi), is there anyway to do this with out creating a database using java script?

If I cant come up with anything, I may have to re-do everything and use a SQL DB for it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can have a JSON object in the Form which will hold all the zip code and email. something like this -

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var emails = [{zip:12345,email:'test@email.com'},{zip:12312,email:'test@email.com'},{zip:12123,email:'email@test.com'}];
</script>
```

then you can get the email address by iterating through the object array using javascript. if you use jquery then you would to something like this to iterate

```
$.each(emails,function(i,item){
    if(item.zip == zip_code_in_address)
        variable_to_hold_email = item.email;
});
```

check the JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RZdE8/)